# Where to download previous  version of wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I would appreciate if someone give me some pointers where I can download older version of wxPython (2.3 to 2.6)

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: An older version of wxPython or one for an earlier Python version?

Answer (score 3):

`wxPython` is hosted on [its own SourceForge area](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/) so that's where you should go for the older stuff.

Unfortunately it only goes back to `2.4.2.4` so I'm not sure where you could source the `2.3` stream.

Answer (score 0):

wxPython2.6.3.3 is available also for python 2.3 :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.6.3.3/
(the version number of wxPython does not correspond to the version number of Python)